# Install kde on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde

My company gave me a laptop setup with ubuntu 14.04. I would like to install KDE however there seems to be an issue:

```
root@ufc3fdb86dd16574fead4:/home/local/ANT/bogoyche# aptitude install kubuntu-desktop
...A list of packages...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1-mesa : Conflicts: libegl1-x11 which is a virtual package.
 xserver-xorg-lts-wily : Conflicts: libegl1-mesa (>= 0~) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6 is to be installed.
                         Conflicts: libwayland-egl1-mesa (>= 0~) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6 is to be installed.
 libegl1-mesa-lts-wily : Conflicts: libegl1-mesa but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6 is to be installed.
                         Conflicts: libegl1-x11 which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     kde-window-manager [Not Installed]                 
2)     kde-workspace [Not Installed]                      
3)     kubuntu-desktop [Not Installed]                    
4)     libegl1-mesa [Not Installed]                       
5)     libwayland-egl1-mesa [Not Installed]               

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
6)     plasma-netbook recommends kde-workspace            
7)     plasma-desktop recommends kde-workspace
```

AFAIK this part of this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1424263 but I can't resolve the dependencies.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the error showing "lts-wily". Ubuntu 14.04 is Trusty Tahr and 15.10 is Wily Werewolf. So I'm confused as to if kubuntu-desktop is trying to install for 15.10 or if  for some reason you have 15.10 installs of the mesa files and kubuntu-desktop is trying to downgrade them to 14.04.

Comment: what do you get when you do `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: @JohnOrion i get the following: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kubuntu-desktop : Depends: kde-window-manager but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: kde-workspace but it is not going to be installed`

How do I check if I have partial wily werewolf installs? The machine has some heavily modified image, but I do have root access so I can change things.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you can tell to be honest... i just noticed the discrepancy and it made me question it. There is one thing you can try but not sure if it would cause issues or solve them ... `sudo apt-get -f install -o Dpkg::Options::= --force-overwrite”` this should cause it to overwrite the conflicts ... this should work and be fine but if maybe some other package installed newer versions because it needed them to run then those other packages may fail.

Comment: @JohnOrion can I somehow view a list of the conflicting files? Then I can tell if they would cause issues or not.

Comment: the conflicts are with the files listed above ... i guess if you wanted to find each file that those conflicts involve you could use synaptic and in the preferences there is a setting to "show package properties in the main window" then there is an "Installed files" tab so you can highlight the program and look at the installed files. ... a lot of work

Comment: crap .. missed a quote on the command and now its too late to edit it here it is again properly `sudo apt-get -f install -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite"`

Comment: I have libegl1-mesa and libegl1-mesa-dev installed on my system .. the other packages like libegl1-mesa-lts-wily is also available for me to install even though I'm on 16.04 .. so I may have got it wrong about you having newer installed .. that may just be the transitional packages like I list

Comment: So the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: well there is still the conflicts... but it may not be because you have the 'wrong' stuff installed... I really am not clear on this. I'm not sure why they are conflicting or what the downfall would be if you forced the versions that KDE needs

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for some reason my image contains some backported packages from newer distros. I solved the problem by installing the conflicting wayland package:

```
aptitude install libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily
```

Then I was able to install `kubuntu-desktop` normally.